# NUnit checking all the values of an array (with tolerance)

Tags: c#, nunit

In NUnit I am able to do the following:

```
Assert.That(1.05,Is.EqualTo(1.0).Within(0.1));
```

I am also able to do that:

```
Assert.That(new[]{1.0,2.0,3.0},Is.EquivalentTo(new[]{3.0,2.0,1.0}));
```

Now I would like to do something along these line

```
Assert.That(new[]{1.05,2.05,3.05},
   Is.EquivalentTo(new[]{3.0,2.0,1.0}).Within(0.1));
```

Except the `Within` keyword is not supported in that situation. Is there a workaround or another approach that would allow to do that easily?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the default tolerance for floating points:

```
GlobalSettings.DefaultFloatingPointTolerance = 0.1;
Assert.That(new[] {1.05, 2.05, 3.05}, Is.EquivalentTo(new[] {3.0, 2.0, 1.0}));
```

Comment: That's what I was searching for. It would be even better if it was local to a single test but its good enough for now. Thanks

Comment: I don't think setting the floating point tolerance for all your app tests is a good idea, it might cause side effects in other tests. The answer by maciejkow doesn't have side effect and will be better (albeit his comment about sorting).

Answer (score 9):

You can do:

```
var actual = new[] {1.05, 2.05, 3.05};
var expected = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected).Within(0.1));
```

However, `Is.EqualTo` semantics is somewhat different from `Is.EquivalentTo` - `EquivalentTo` ignores order ( `{1, 2, 3}` is equivalent, but not equal to `{2, 1, 3}`). If you'd like to preserve this semantics, the simplest solution is to sort arrays before assertion. If you're going to use this construct a lot I would suggest to write your own constraint for that.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use `EqualTo` to check the array values.  Like this:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Validate the array is within a specified amount
  /// </summary>
  [Test]
  public void ValidateArrayWithinValue()
  {
     var array1 = new double[] { 0.0023d, 0.011d, 0.743d };
     var array2 = new double[] { 0.0033d, 0.012d, 0.742d };

     Assert.That(array1, Is.EqualTo(array2).Within(0.00101d), "Array Failed Constaint!");
  } // ValidateArrayWithinValue
```

Comment: I believe that Benoittr would like to preserve semantics of Is.EquivalentTo. Your test does not ignore ordering of items in arrays.